# Configure istio for both tls and MTLS

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I have a Kubernetes app and I'm having the istio sidecar set up. Is it possible configure istio MTLS for a subset of APIs and others with simple TLS?

Comment: If I understand correctly you should be able to do that with [destination rules](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule), as you can use the [tls settings mode](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings-TLSmode) to change the mtls  for specific hosts. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: I believe if you had spent 5 minutes reading the documentation, you'd know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should be able to do that with [destination rules](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/), as you can use the [tls settings mode](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings-TLSmode) to change the mtls for specific hosts.

Take a look at below examples from [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings):

> For example, the following rule configures a client to use mutual TLS for connections to upstream database cluster.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: db-mtls
spec:
  host: mydbserver.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/certs/myclientcert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/client_private_key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/rootcacerts.pem
```

> The following rule configures a client to use TLS when talking to a foreign service whose domain matches *.foo.com.

```
v1alpha3v1beta1
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: tls-foo
spec:
  host: "*.foo.com"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
```

> The following rule configures a client to use Istio mutual TLS when talking to rating services.

```
v1alpha3v1beta1
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: ratings-istio-mtls
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```